# why can't i change my html content by queryselectorall and getelementbyclass name?

Tags: javascript, google-web-designer

why my console does not recognize the getElementByClassName and getElementByTagName and querySelectorAll methods while it know getElementById and querySelector?and I can not change the style with querySelector

Comment: `getElementByClassName` should be `getElementsByClassName` plural. Same with `getElementByTagName` it's `getElementsByTagName` again. As for `querySelectorAll` it's correct but I suspect you're using it as if it returns a single element: [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10693845)

Comment: Well first off, neither `getElementByClassName` nor `getElementByTagName` are functions, the actual methods `getElementsByClassName` and `getElementsByTagName` (plural element***s***). Please provide code, and what does this have to do with `google-web-designer`?

Comment: thanks for your answer I changed it and it still does not work.
mydoc=document.getElementsByClassName("forth");
mydoc.innerHTML="change me please"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`mydoc=document.getElementsByClassName("forth");` returns a HTMLCollection object. HTMLCollection does not have a innerHTML property. You need to access a specific element of the collection through it's index. I.e.

`mydoc[0].innerHTML = "change me please";`
or
`mydoc = document.getElementsByClassName("forth")[0];`